# Is there an axiomatic system for propositional logic that does not use modus ponens as a rule?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Is there an axiomatic system for (classical) propositional logic that does not use modus ponens as a (primitive) rule?

I would be particularly interested in a derivation of it from some other set of rules. I would assume that this is possible with rules only for, e. g., $\wedge$ and $\neg$, but I've never seen it done before.

Comment: Any system with the following rules (as primitive or derivable) as well as the usual monotonicity and transitivity rules doesn't need MP as primitive:

$$\{a\rightarrow b\}\vdash \neg a\vee b\quad\mbox{and}\quad \{a, \neg a\vee b\}\vdash b.$$ And the first of those can be completely ignored if we agree to treat "$a\rightarrow b$" as an abbreviation for "$\neg a\vee b$" in the first place. Does that count?

Comment: The cut-free $\{\wedge,\neg\}$ fragment of the [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK) does the job. Just define $A \vee B$ as an abbreviation for $\neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$, and $A \rightarrow B$ as $\neg (A \wedge \neg B)$.

Comment: See Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic (Addison-Wesley, 1967)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic/oEsPEAAAQBAJ) (page 21)

Comment: @Z.A.K. If I understood you correctly, in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894022/is-there-any-finite-deductive-system-for-propositional-logic-which-only-uses-una?rq=1 you gave an axiom system, which doesn't use modus ponens as a primitive, since modus ponens has two premises, and the rules you gave were all had one premise.  The primitive connectives, were → and ¬.